# How to write JavaScript code as plain text in Wordpress blog post

Tags: wordpress

I want to write some javascript code in my wordpress hosted website as  plain text. But whenever I see the in live, the code code get omitted. How do I resolve the problem means How do I post script code as plain text?

I want to replace the following code:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
    </script> 
<script>
```

With the following code:

```
      <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js">
      </script>
```

`&lt;script&gt;
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
  &lt;/script&gt;
</pre>`

Comment: You can install plugins like crayon highlighter where you'll write your code. Or try to put your code in `<pre>` tags. Who knows, might work...

Comment: Sorry I'm not authorized to install plugin..

Answer (score 1):

This is covered [right in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts). You'll need to convert `<` and `>` characters to their character entity counterparts. For example:

```html
<pre>
  &lt;script&gt;
    var javaScript = 'cool!';
  &lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

Comment: I have updated the Question. Can you please suggest what's mistake in my code please?

Comment: You need to change ALL `<` to `&lt;` and ALL `>` to `&gt;`

Comment: Your code should be added to the "text" editor in the Admin instead of the Visual editor. Try that and let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have rewrite in text editor and  when I see in visual editor it's works fine but when I see the live site..I see the same Error.